# Simple ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I'm trying to store a one-to-many relationship in my mySQL database and I want to avoid duplicate entries if at all possible.

I read on the internet and saw that 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' is an option. Would this work for my situation?

**CODE:**

```
function insert_options($uid, $array) {
    if(!is_array($array)) {
        return false;
    }
    $db = db_connect();
    foreach($array as $a) {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO newsletter_coupon_codes_options (uid, option_name, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        if($stmt === false) {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error;
        }
        $stmt->bind_param('iss', $uid, $a, $value);
        $value = '1';
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

**TABLE**

```
UID(INT11), OPTION_NAME(varchar(255)), VALUE(INT(11))
```

I tried to add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 1` to the `$sql` statement, but it didn't seem to do anything. Basically I want to make sure when I'm inserting the data if the `uid` and `option_name` exist, it just sets the `value` to `1` and doesn't make a new entry.

I do not have a unique key set up, only a primary key on `uid`. I wasn't sure what to make unique. I can't make the `uid` unique, as there will be multiple entries per `uid`. I also cannot make the `option_name` unique as there will be the same option_name for multiple `uid`'s

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: have you added unique key in that table ..

Comment: @Sundar > Nope. I only have a PK which is `uid`. I wasn't sure what to make unique. I can't make the `uid` unique, as there will be multiple entries per `uid`. I also cannot make the `option_name` unique as there will be the same `option_name` for multiple `uid`'s. Could you recommend something?

Comment: You should use unique key to update the entry. Primary key lookup is faster so you can split the process first check the duplication after decide insert or to update. But primary key also supports for duplication update http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: You want `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to

```sql
INSERT INTO newsletter_coupon_codes_options (uid, option_name, value) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37cfc/1)** demo

And **make sure** that you have a `UNIQIE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on `(uid, option_name)`, e.g.

```sql
ALTER TABLE newsletter_coupon_codes_options 
  ADD UNIQUE (uid, option_name);
```

Comment: The constraint on `(uid, option_name)` was exactly what I didn't know and was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please change your query like this and use mysqli_query function execute this kindof queries and use mysqli_real_escape_string function to avoid SQL injections

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO newsletter_coupon_codes_options 
     (uid, option_name, value) VALUES ("'.$uid.'", "'.$option_name.'", "'.$value.'")
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  value = "'.$value.'"';
```

Comment: -1 for suggesting to use query strings interpolation, which leads to sql injections, instead of using prepared statements

Comment: the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause is malformed